Traces condition of old Nokia logic board
The following are the pics of traces on logic board of Nokia. The traces are where display connector was attached but somehow the 10-pin connector got torn off exposing the traces.
I want to know if these traces show rust? Do the condition appear ok given the pictures below? I am planning on buying the 10-pin connector to soder it back but they are hard to source and are bit expensive so want to know if these traces look like it can be done?



It's not rust (there's no iron here), but there does appear to be some form of corrosion. Try to clean the pads off with a soldering iron and flux; until you do that, we can't tell if the pads were lifted or not.

@Hearth i see. Makes sense. Do I also use copper mesh for cleaning or just sodering iron and flux is enough?
